# dynamic replace the RegExp object without slashes

Tags: jquery, regex

I have prblem with dynamically created `RegExp` object (in the [file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/))

This is a initialization code of the plugin:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(doc|pdf)$/i
});
```

That code changes the regex:

```
$('#files-list').change(function() {
   $('#fileupload').fileupload(
            'option',
            'acceptFileTypes',
            new RegExp('(\.|\/)('+$(this).find(":selected").attr('f-ext')+')$/i')
                );
            });
```

and it adds the `/` char at the beggining and at the end of that regex.

See the image below. The 1st & 2nd line is after the plugin initialization, the 3rd and the 4th line. That causes the file name validation fail.

[image]

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use case insensitive modifier you should do the next

```
new RegExp( regexp_expression , 'i' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifiers for JS regexes, when supplied in constructor function, should be specified separately:

```
...new RegExp('(\.|\/)('+$(this).find(":selected").attr('f-ext')+')$', 'i');
```

The [general syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is:

```
var newRegex = new RegExp(pattern [, flags]);
```